# Xcode 4.3.2: Breakpoints stops working - Xcode does not show the code

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging

I am experiencing some strange problems with different iOS projects in Xcode 4.3.2:

The normal behaviour of breakpoint should be like this:
If the program execution reaches the code line with a breakpoint the execution stops and the code line is shown in Xcode. One can then use the "Continue", "Step over" or "Step into" functions go ahead with the execution. Using "Step over" or "Step into" will show the code line which will be executed next.

The first part (stopping the execution when reaching a breapoint) works without any problem. But Xcode does not show the corresponding code line. After the execution stopped I can use the Step functions but again Xcode will not show the code line. This way the breakpoints are pretty useless since I cannot see where the execution stopped.

The problem does not always show up. Sometimes it works and then in suddenly stops working. One time a break point works and during the next execution it does not work.

Most of the time stopping the execution and running the app again solves the problem. But it is just a matter of time till it stops working again. Sometimes only restarting Xcode has any effect.

BTW: The debugger is set to GDB since LLDB has other problems.

I found some other posts dealing with breakpoint problems. But in all cases the problem was different to one I am experiencing (execution did not stop at all, breakpoint where disabled automatically, etc.).

Does anyone know this problem or has an idea how to solve it?

Andrei

Comment: I think your problem is the usage of Xcode. Have you tried to click the different view buttons in the upper right corner.

Comment: I do not see how the views could effect the problem. Most of the time I use the "Standard Editor" view together with "Navigator", "Debug" and "Utilities" view. One time the problems shows up while using this config and one time it does not. So how could that be the source of the problem? Or do you mean the buttons in the debug area? Here I always use the split view to the variables and the console. Again I do not see any connection to the problem.